# React Native [Error: Camera is not running] Existe alguna forma de reiniciar la camara dentro de una view en espeficico?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Tengo un botón que quita fotos, funciona muy bien dentro de una vista, puede quitar varias fotos 
(El resultado en la consola)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la imagen en el cel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el código

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';


import { Camera, Permissions } from 'expo';


const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
class Teste extends Component {
    state = {
    hasCameraPermission: null,
    type: Camera.Constants.Type.front,
    camara: null
  };


  press = () => {

    if (this.camera) {
      this.camera.takePictureAsync({
        base64: true,
        quality: 0.5
      }).
      then(data => {
        //console.log(`data:image/jpg;base64,${data.base64}`)
        if (data.base64){
          console.log("quite una foto");  
        }
        //Actions.prueba() comentando esto, puedo obtener varias fotos
      }).catch(e => console.log(e))
     }


  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={height <= 650 && width <= 450? stylesMin.container : styles.container}>

        {

      <Camera
        style={{ height: 300, width: 300 }}
        type={this.state.type}
        ref={ref => {
          this.camera = ref;
        }}>
      </Camera>

    }


      <View style={height <= 650 && width <= 450? stylesMin.contTopRight : styles.contTopRight }>
        <TouchableHighlight 
        onPress={() => this.press() } 
        activeOpacity={0.7}
        style={height <= 650 && width <= 450? stylesMin.button : styles.button }
        >
          <Text style={height <= 650 && width <= 450? stylesMin.caja : styles.caja }>Photo</Text>                
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>



      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Teste
```

hasta ahí, no tengo problema quitar una foto, el problema viene cuando le agrego otra ruta (descomento el código de arriba en action)

```
if (this.camera) {
  this.camera.takePictureAsync({
    base64: true,
    quality: 0.5
  }).
  then(data => {
    //console.log(`data:image/jpg;base64,${data.base64}`)
    if (data.base64){
      console.log("quite una foto");  
    }
    Actions.prueba() //esta linea
  }).catch(e => console.log(e))
}
```

quita una foto y tengo una vista como esta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la lógica que me devuelve a la camara

```
volver = () => {
  console.log("volvere a la foto");
   Actions.test()
}
```

esta es la imagen en el cel

al volver a la pantalla de la cámara queda asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esto es lo que imprime, al intentar quitar otra foto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

por si a alguien le pase lo mismo, solucione el error utilizando DrawerNavigator de react-navigation en App.js, en vez de Route de react-native-router-flux